# How would I query, then toggle Windows updates off and on via a batch file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, windows-update

Please take it easy on me if I speak out of place is this is my first post. :-) but I've been looking for a way to query the Windows Update service through a batch file and based on its current state, either turn it off or on. Ultimately, I want to be able to query if the service is started, then stop it. On top of that, I want to be able to query if its set to auto start with Windows and disable. Then i was the same batch file to query and possibly go the other. like if on, turn off. If off, turn on. or possibly query, then give the option to leave off/on or change the state and start of the service.

I found out how to do these things separately (mostly through this site) by using the following commands:

- sc start wuauserv
- sc stop wuauserv
- Query wuauserv
- sc config wuauserv start= auto
- sc config wuauserv start= disabled

So with these i can create two different files to both stop the service and disable it on startup and a separate file to start the service and set the startup to auto, but I would like to do all this with one file if possible.

So this was so long but wanted to make sure I got my goal across and show that i did do some preemptive research.

Update:
Had to zoom in a little bit on your example:
[image]
This is what mine looks like when i right clicked on the .bat file i created and run it as admin:
[image]

I noticed that you appear to be using Windows 8.1 and im on Windows 7. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
@echo off
@title Windows Update Status Tool
IF "%~1"=="" goto ERROR
IF "%~1"=="q" goto Q
IF "%~1"=="disable" goto DISABLE
IF "%~1"=="stop" goto STOP
IF "%~1"=="start" goto START
IF "%~1"=="enable" goto ENABLE
:Q
sc query wuauserv
pause
goto EOF
:DISABLE
sc config wuauserv start=disabled
echo Done!
pause
goto EOF
:STOP
sc stop wuauserv
goto EOF
:START
sc start wuauserv
goto EOF
:ENABLE
sc config wuauserv start=auto
echo Done!
pause
goto EOF
:ERROR
echo Invalid command! Valid syntax is: q, disable, enable, stop, start.
pause
goto EOF
:EOF
```

Keep in mind that this batch file needs to be run as an admin to be used. It accepts the parameters `q, start, stop, enable, disable` and can be run using this syntax `winupd q` replace q with the item you want the file to do.

Example: [image: script demo]

Comment: Thanks for the response. but when i copy and paste that code into a test.bat it goes straight to "Invalid command! Valid syntax is: q, disable, enable, stop, start." Is there something i need to in order to get it to run? i am running it as admin and normally with the same results

Comment: @RidleyJ329 you need to run it with syntax, i.e. `winupd q` or `winupd start`

Comment: Sorry if im maybe missing a simple step somewhere but it still does not appear to be working for me. i attached some images to my original post

Comment: @RidleyJ329 use the syntax it states. If you look at the image in my answer, I've given the script a  which is `q` for query. to use it, you need to put that script in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder so you can call it from the command line like I did

Comment: @RidleyJ329 You need to give the script something to do, which is why there are commands. you need to give it